# How do I get the Nightingale out of the water?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at the final objective of the mission "Blindsighted".

> This mission involves entering Irkngthand to confront Mercer Frey, the Thieves' Guild leader on the lam. The final objective is to "Speak to Karliah".

Unfortunately, I cannot complete it because the person that I must speak to won't stop swimming around aimlessly in the waters of the final room. How do I fix them?

Comment: I guess it's not such a big deal for now since the mission reward scales to the player-character's level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before leaving the sanctuary, be sure to talk to Karliah or both she and Brynjolf may become stuck underwater. At this point you will not be able to talk to her, essentially breaking the quest.

- Use the console commands prid 58F1A and then moveto player. This way you can talk to her and continue the quest.
- Alternatively, you can try swimming and bumping into Karliah repeatedly to knock her into the correct path and out of the water, at which point she will continue normally. This may take a while, so it is a good idea to have a waterbreathing enchanted item with you to prevent drowning (if you are not playing as an Argonian).
- Another option is to shoot her with arrows when she is in sight from the land. She will run up at you. If you have a potion of paralysis, paralyze her when she is on land. Exit and come back.

Source: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blindsighted)

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the skeleton key and Karliah proceeds back into the water (where glitch occurs) return to the cave, go back into the water, but wade so that your chest and head aren't submerged. turn around a few times and you'll notice a head bobbing (it's Karliah) slowly...I mean SLOWLY approach her until you have the ability to talk. You should be able to return the key and complete the mission despite the glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Put on Ahzidal's Boots of Water Walking. Walk over to Karliah and shoot just below the arrow over her head. She will come to the surface so you can speak to her. Once you are done take the boots off so you don't get stuck on the rocks overhead and swim back to shore.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an accepted answer, but a solution worked for me:
**I used a shout**, specifically **Aura Whisper**. Not sure if other shouts would work too.
After using it, surprisingly both of them swim towards me and even run straight out of the tunnel ahead of me.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a housecarl or a follower you can get them to attack the person, that’s what i did and it worked, but then she went right back to standing underwater, though i was still able to talk to her and finish the quest. just know that this will get the guards to attack you but it’s skyrim so you can just ignore them when they try to arrest you.

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer that encompasses more than what your new answer has to offer. Either edit your answer to provide additional information or delete it altogether.